# Prevent review form and review summary rating cache with Varnish and Turpentine

Tags: magento-1.7, varnish, turpentine

How can I prevent this block from caching? 
Product review form should just be visible by logged in users, is candidate:
INFO (6): TURPENTINE: Checking ESI block candidate: product.review.form
I have added this to my local.xml:

```
 <reference type="review/product_view_list" name="product.review.form">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                    <access>private</access>
                    <registry_keys>
                    <current_category/>
                    <current_product/>
                    </registry_keys>
            </params>
            </action>
    </reference>
```

But it still get cached.

The review summary has not block candidate how should I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Nexcess's https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine ?

Comment: yes I'm using magento-turpentine

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution to this question, I am facing the same issue on magento 1.9.1

Comment: The issue is reproducible and I have found a solution. If somebody re-opens this question I will post my answer here.